# Modifying existing text element with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, dynamic-text, text-element

I have a text element in the top right corner of my template project file that has some text, then the current date. Then some more text follows and then the next date appears which is 10 years later than the first one.
So far i've been using this block of text but I keep having to add the +10 year date manually:
SOME TEXT
SOME TEXT `<dyn type="document" property="date saved" format="short"/>`
SOME TEXT *Document date saved but +10 years*
SOME TEXT

I'd love to make a script that fills in both of the dates for me automatically. Reading about using Text element for arcpy has gotten me confused and I've tried to combine some sort of code through various other similar questions but I haven't quite figured it out.

This is something that i've managed to gather from other answers on this site:

```
from arcpy import env 


env.workspace = r"PATH"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"PATH\\" + mxdname)
    for TextElement in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if TextElementName == "TextElementName":
            TextElement.text = "New Text"
            true
            print 'text'
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

I have replaced the actual path in the code to "PATH".

Could anyone point out a direction on where I should start working or modifying this existing code to solve my problem?